# Fabric Js requestRenderAll() method vs renderAll() method

Tags: fabricjs

With the new 3.0.0 version of Fabric JS we have to apply `requestRenderAll()` in order to see the handles when one objects is **active**. 
**My question is:** 
does `requestRenderAll()` replace some kind `renderAll()` method. Are there any important differences between both methods. When we have to use each of them and do we have to use them together?

I now that `Canvas.renderall` is a sync operation and `requestRenderAll()` method is regarded as improvemnt. But do we still need `renderAll()` and if "yes", when. And also - is `renderAll()` going to be deprecated in near future?

Comment: calling (requestRenderAll)[http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#requestRenderAll], if one render request is running it wont render again otherwise it will call `renderAll()`. If you want to force render , then you can call `renderAll`. renderAll won't be deprecate ever.

Comment: Thank you @Durga for this clarification!